# B2 to F1 visa changed in the US eligibility for revalidation entry the US

Tags: usa, visa

Would someone, who initially entered the US with b2 visa and then changed to f1 visa, be eligible for revalidation of visa or to reenter the US if traveled to adjacent islands for less than 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone who did Change of Status in the US can use automatic revalidation to re-enter the US in the new status if they meet the conditions of automatic revalidation. See [this FAQ](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/auto_reva_3.pdf) from the CBP:

> The validity of an expired nonimmigrant visa may be considered to be
>   automatically extended to the date of application for readmission at
>   ports of entry. **This includes cases where U.S. Citizenship and
>   Immigration Services has changed the nonimmigrant classifications of
>   an alien to another nonimmigrant classification.** The validity of an
>   expired or unexpired nonimmigrant visa may be considered to be
>   automatically extended to the date of readmission **and the visa may
>   be converted as necessary to that changed classification**. [22.C.F.R.
>   41.112(d)]

(emphasis added by me)